# Transit visa for Serbia

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, south-african-citizens, belgrade

On our return to South Africa from Moscow, we have a 10 hour layover in Belgrade. Can we leave the airport to do a visit of the city?  Will we need a transit visa for this purpose? If yes, where and how does one apply for this?

Comment: What passport do you have? South African?

Comment: south African. so no visa for Moscow. Our layover is in Belgrade Serbia

Comment: Do you have a valid visa for the EU or USA?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where else are you stopping?  (As far as I can tell, there aren't any scheduled flights between Belgrade & South Africa, so you must have a second layover elsewhere.)

Comment: I have a visa for USA - valid until 2026 . This was issued to me on my South African passport

Comment: our entire flight is from Moscow to Belgrade - 10 hour lay over . thereafter a connection to Abu Dhabi -  3 hour layover , thereafter a connection to Johannesburg

Answer (score 1):

> For the issuance of a transit visa, you should have an entry visa for
>   the country you are entering after the Republic of Serbia. In case a
>   visa is not required for that country, you will be asked to present
>   other documents explaining the purpose of your visit there.

http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-requirements

> At its meeting of 30 October 2014, the Government of the Republic of
>   Serbia adopted the Decision on visa free entry to the Republic of
>   Serbia for holders of foreign passports having a valid Schengen, UK
>   and other Member States' visa, or visa of the United States of
>   America, and for holders of foreign passports having residence permit
>   in the countries of the Schengen area, EU or the United States of
>   America, which was published in the "Official Gazette of RS", No. 119
>   of 31 October 2014 and which will enter into force on 8 November 2014.
>
> By this decision, the above-mentioned categories of foreign nationals
>   may, without prior visa application, enter, transit or stay in the
>   Republic of Serbia up to 90 days during a six-month period, but not
>   exceeding the expiring date of the said visas or residence permits.
>
> There is a possibility for foreign nationals to enter the Republic of
>   Serbia with two passports e.a. expired national passport with valid
>   visa or residence permit and valid national passport without valid
>   visa or residence permit.

http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/consular-affairs/entry-serbia/visa-regime

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=ZA&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=RS&selTrans=Serbia&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a multiple entry or
>   an unused one-entry visa issued by Switzerland, USA or an EEA
>   Member State or:. The visa must be valid for the
>   period of intended stay.

So if you have one of the mentioned visas, you can Exit the Airport. Otherwise, you Need a Serbian Transit visa for that.

Comment: thank you for all the feedback - will hopefully be able to use my USA visa to exit. if this is not allowed I will update this site after 20th Sep

Comment: @safia It is allowed, I assure you